# How to set a Wordpress static html front page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to set a wordpress static html front page, which doesn't seem trivial.

I tried three approaches:

1) add a index.html, and rename index.php to blog.php. Change the permalink into custom: `/blog.php?p=%postid%`. However for handling categories, the generated link is `/blog.php?p=cat=3`.

2) add a index.html, and rename index.php to blog.php. Change the installation position into `www.mydomain.com/blog.php` in my dashboard. This time it direct to `www.mydomain.com/blog.php/?p=123`.

3) add a page and set it to be displayed as frontpage in my dashboard/settings/reading. However for this solution, I don't know how to change the overall html of a page edited in wordpress. I can only modify the html for the body but I need to change it whole.

Any suggestions?

Comment: belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a home.php inside your theme folder and write whatever you want inside it. You can ignore any theme's code, just plain HTML would be enough for this file.

WordPress will process the homepage with this file without any extra settings.